# Trato de importar una imagen en react.js a mi componente pero no lo hace

Tags: reactjs

trato de insertar una imagen a traves de hooks de react.js cuando lo hago resulta que la imagen no aparece entonces quisiera saber en que me estoy equivocando.

```
    import React, {useState} from 'react';
import NavigationItems from "./NavigationItems/NavigationItems";
import classes from "./Header.module.css";
import Logo from "../../LogoComp/Logo.js";

const Header = () => {

  const [useSrc] = useState(["src/assets/Logo.png"])
  const [useAlt] = useState(['Logo-Blog'])
  return (
  <header className={classes.Header}>
    <Logo Link="/"
    src={useSrc}
    alt={useAlt} />
    <NavigationItems></NavigationItems> 
  </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: ¿Qué errores te salen en la consola de JavaScript?

Comment: En primera, estas pasando un arreglo a `useState` entonces tu estado es un arreglo de una string, por lo que tendrias que acceder a ese string asi `useSrc[0]`. En segunda, no creo que puedas acceder a tus imagenes con esa, podrias mover tus imagenes a la carpeta `public` y en tercera, necesitas guardar las rutas de tus imagenes en el state?